# How does the enumerable module works by just adding an each method on a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I'm learning ruby and while studding modules I found that for making Enumerable module methods accessible inside a class you should also provide a each method inside your class. I don't really understand why doing this is making enumerable methods work.

Also, i don't understand why i don't need to call the each method please be kind I'm just beginning to learn

```rb
class List 
  include Enumerable
  
  def initialize (*list)
    @list = *list
  end

  def each(&block)
    @list.each(&block)
  end
end

Mylist = List.new(1,2,3,4,5)

puts Mylist.any? {|num| num>2}
```

I'm planning to create my own Enumerable module whit some of the Enumerable methods and I think understanding this concept will help me on doing it.

Comment: Hint: `Enumerable` becomes an `ancestor` of `List` which means methods defined there can work on any `List` instance. In Ruby you can gain methods through *inheritance*, as in a parent class, or through *composition*, where you `include` or `extend` to add new ones.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`. Here `Mylist` should be something like `my_list` or just `list`.

Comment: If you want to capture the arguments as an array, `@list = list` is what you mean. The `*` (splat) operator is not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first define instances of some classes that include the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html) module.

```
require 'set'

arr = [1, 2, 3]
hsh = { 1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4 }
rng = (1..3)
set = (1..3).to_set
```

Suppose an enumerable method is defined as follows.

```
module Enumerable
  def reverse_em
    a = []
    each { |e| a.unshift(e) }
    a
  end
end
```

We may then write:

```
arr.reverse_em #=> [3, 2, 1]
hsh.reverse_em #=> [[:c, 3], [:b, 2], [:a, 1]]
rng.reverse_em #=> [3, 2, 1]
set.reverse_em #=> [3, 2, 1]
```

As you see, a single `Enumerable` method is used by instances of four different classes. This obviously is a superior design construct to defining `reverse_em` for each of the four classes.

As `each` in `each { |e| a.unshift(e) }` has no explicit receiver the implicit receiver is used. In `[1, 2, 3].reverse_em`, for example, the implicit receiver is `[1, 2, 3]` so `each { |e| a.unshift(e) }` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3].each { |e| a.unshift(e) }`
with `each` being an instance method of the class `Array`.

To implement this functionality each of the class definitions for `Array`, `Hash`, `Range` and `Set` (and other core classes) must have a statement `include Enumerable` and must contain an instance method `each` that returns an enumerator ([Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each), [Hash#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-each), [Range#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-each) and [Set#each](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-each)).

Note that `reverse_em` returns an array regardless of the receiver's class. That is the case with many if not all `Emumerable` methods.

If follows that a user's custom class can make use of all of the methods in the `Enumerable` module by including in the class definition the statement `include Enumerable` and an instance method `each` that returns an enumerator. Note that a few `Enumerable` methods depend on methods other than `each` that are to be provided by the class.

---

Now let's take a second example where the `Enumerable` method must account for the possibility that a block is passed. Specifically, let's consider how [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) might be coded.

```
module Enumerable
  def my_map
    return each unless block_given?
    a = []
    each { |e| a << yield(e) }
    a
  end
end
```

Firstly, if no block is passed an enumerator is returned that simply enumerates the elements of the receiver (as with `Enumerable#map`).

```
arr.my_map #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
hsh.my_map #=> #<Enumerator: {1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4}:each>
rng.my_map #=> #<Enumerator: 1..3:each>
set.my_map #=> #<Enumerator: #<Set: {1, 2, 3}>:each>
```

Now suppose a block is passed.

```
arr.my_map { |e| 2*e }   #=> [2, 4, 6]
hsh.my_map { |k,v| k*v } #=> [2, 6, 12]
rng.my_map { |n| n**2 }  #=> [1, 4, 9]
set.my_map { |n| n**2 }  #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Note that the methods in `Enumerable` don't call `next` on the enumerator returned by `each` – they always pass a block to `each` and expect it to _yield_ the elements. An implementation in `Enumerable` would be more like `a = [] ; each { |e| a.unshift(e) } ; a`.

Answer (score 4):

Module `Enumerable` is designed such way

Every `Enumerable` method uses `each` method which yields successive members of the collection. That's why you just need implement it and include `Enumerable` in your class

If you will use `max`, `min`, or `sort` methods, you also need to implement `<=>` method